# In java 8 lambdas, how to access original object in the stream?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of 'A'

```
List<A> as;
```

If I want to do a fair bit of processing on each A, and at the end of the processing, I want to take the result and put it in another field of A, what is the best way to do that?

ie

```
as.stream().
map(a -> a.getX()).
filter(x -> x != null).
map(x -> lookup.get(x)).

At this point how to say y -> a.setLookedUpVal(y)?
```

I've lost the reference to 'a' further up in the lambda chain. Is there any way to store it and refer back to it or something?

Comment: If the lookup is bound to `x` I'd rather suggest to change your code to get something like `a.lookup(lookup::get)`. Then you would have a simple `forEach`.

Comment: `for(A a: as) if(a.getX()!=null) a.setLookedUpVal(lookup.get(a.getX()));` or, if `getX()` is expensive, `for(A a: as) { X x=a.getX(); if(x!=null) a.setLookedUpVal(lookup.get(x)); }`. Compare every Stream based solution with *that* before deciding to use it…

Answer (score 13):

If you have more complex scenario or don't like @Aaron answer for some reason, you can do the flatMap-capturing trick creating one-element stream per each outer element:

```
as.stream().
   flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a.getX()).
      filter(x -> x != null).
      map(x -> a)).
   forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here we have nested per-element stream where you can do any stateless stream operations (`map`, `filter`, `peek` and `flatMap`) having a reference to the original element. After original element becomes unnecessary, you close the `flatMap` and continue with original stream. Example:

```
Stream.of("a", "bb", "ccc", "dd", "eeee")
    .flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a.length())
            .filter(x -> x > 2)
            .map(x -> a))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
// prints "ccc" and "eeee".
```

Or two filters:

```
Stream.of("a", "bb", "ccc", "dd", "eeee")
    .flatMap(a -> Stream.of(a.length())
            .filter(x -> x > 2)
            .map(x -> a.charAt(0)) // forget the length, now check the first symbol
            .filter(ch -> ch == 'c')
            .map(x -> a)) // forget the first symbol, reverting to the whole string
    .forEach(System.out::println);
// prints only "ccc"
```

Of course such simple scenarios could be rewritten like @Aaron suggests, but in more complex cases flatMap-capturing may be suitable solution.

Comment: Or `.flatMap(a -> a.length()>2 && a.charAt(0)=='c'? Stream.of(a): null)` which is almost as concise as using `.filter`…

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can access the unmodified elements, but you could rework your operations chain in the following way :

```
as.stream()
  .filter(a -> a.getX() != null)
  .forEach(a -> a.setLookedUpVal(lookup.get(a.getX()))
```

Now I understand it makes it more complex and might not be interesting in solving your real-world problem.
It has, however, the advantage of working all along with a `Stream<A>`, which could in some situations make it simpler and more extensible than having different types at different steps.