# Reference original object after flatMap

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

Is it possible to reference the original object after flatMap?

For example:

```
.flatMap(passenger-> passenger.getAncillaries().stream())                                                                    
.forEach(ancillary -> {
    [Can here reference passenger?]
    foo(passenger, ancillary); ?????
}
```

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: No, you can't. If you want to do something for each `passenger`, either do it before `flatMap` (maybe using `peek`) or during `flatMap`.

Comment: Maybe this would be useful in this situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314626/16034206

Comment: For Joachim: That's not possible, because in the foreach, I need to call a method that uses passenger and ancillary.

Comment: If you need to do something for each passenger/ancillary combo then you might need to do it to the stream you're creating inside `flatMap()`, e.g. `flatMap(pass -> pass.getAncillaries().stream().peek(anc -> /* do it here*/))` or if all you are after is `forEach()` just nest those: `passengers.forEach(pass -> pass.getAncillaries().forEach(anc -> ...))`.

Comment: I think that Thomas's solution is the best, although perhaps it is better to chain the foreach, than to use peek (I have verified it and it works perfectly) but not for totally compliant.

Comment: What does `foo` do?  Would it print something, return an object?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 17, you can do that using a `record` (a class would be fine too in older version):

```
record PassengerAndAncillary(Passenger passenger, Ancillary ancillary) {}

// 
passengers.flatMap(passenger-> passenger.getAncillaries()
                              .stream()
                              .map(ancillary -> new PassengerAndAncillary(passenger, ancillary)                                                                    )
.forEach(pa -> {
    foo(pa.passenger(), pa.ancillary());
});
```

Better then: let foo take PassengerAndAncillary and you are done:

```
.forEach(this::foo)
```

If you don't want to roll up your own class, you can also use:

- [Pair from commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)
- [AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry from JDK itself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html)

You would however be best, in this case where you don't use the `Stream`, to not use a `Stream` at all:

```
passengers.forEach(passenger -> {
  passenger.getAncillaries().forEach(ancillary -> {
    foo(passenger, ancillary);
  });
});
```

--
Edit (for the comment):

I'd say that filtering before/after all boils down to performance issues:

- if you do no filter nor use parallel streams, I do think the `forEach` based loop would be better because you are simply not using the `Stream`.
- if you need only filter on passenger, do it before `flatMap`: the resulting stream would be shorter, resulting in less invocation on `flatMap` function (and less `record PassengerAndAncillary` too).
- if you need only filter on ancillary (not both), do it in the flatMap function: you won't create needless object for unmatched ancillary.
- if you need to perform on both, do it before `forEach` on `PassengerAndAncillary`.

Comment: This solution is great. In the example code, I forgot to put that you have to filter the passengers. Is it possible to make a filter inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0):

in the line of code:

```
.flatMap(passenger-> passenger.getAncillaries().stream())  
// Only Ancillaries type objects exist in the stream
```

so you can not write codes like this:

```
.forEach(ancillary -> {
    passenger.getName();// can not access to the passenger object
}
```

This is the right answer:

```
.flatMap(passenger-> passenger.getAncillaries().stream())                                                                    
.forEach(item -> {
    item.getXXX();//item references 【passenger.getAncillaries()】
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to using `flatMap` is to use [mapMulti (Java 16)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) in conjunction with [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V))

- Stream the passengers as you normally would
- the you can filter the Passenger as required. If the filter predicate returns true, the filtered object is passed thru.
- then invoke `mapMulti`, which takes the streamed object and a consumer. Note that  mapMulti is type witnessed to reflect the new type that is placed on the stream.  In this case `Map.Entry`
- Use a loop to iterate thru the Ancillary list and then package in `Map.Entry`.  `Consumer.accept` puts that on the stream for subsequent processing.

```
passengers.stream()
       .filter(passenger -> passenger.isSomething)
              .<Map.Entry<Passenger, Ancillary>>mapMulti((passenger, consumer) -> {
                    for (Ancillary ancillary : passenger.getAncillaries) {
                        consumer.accept(
                                Map.entry(passenger, ancillary));
                    }
                })
        .forEach(e -> foo(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```